# WIll I need to update my website manually to get new offers - caching on LiteSpeed?

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, litespeed

I have some PHP code in my pages on website that get newest real estate offers from another database. I was wondering when I will install LiteSpeed Cache plugin on this Wordpress website, do I have to manually refresh website to get this new offers?

Comment: Any caching plugin should be able to refresh the pages are a specific time set and should also be able to react to some kind of external trigger. This means that you could write something that is triggered or run by the WP cron system and tries to fetch new offers. If there are new offers, the cache should be deleted or rebuild to include the latest offers. The plugin developers can probably help you with figuring out how to clear the cache via an external trigger.